# Wix - copy file based on combobox property

Tags: wix

When installing an application using Wix, I would like to copy a file to a location based on a ComboBox property then a PushButton with `<Publish Event="DoAction" Value="CustomAction">1</Publish>`.

If I use a Custom Action for this and set `Execute="immediate"`, then the file copy fails with the error `UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code`.

If I set `Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"` in the Custom Action, and add it to `InstallExecuteSequence`, then it runs too early, before a value is set for the ComboBox property, and it fails.

Is there any way that I can get a deferred Custom Action which will only run when a value is selected in the ComboBox and the button is pushed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of getting this to work with `Execute="immediate"` is to open the command prompt as administrator and run the msi from there. This grants sufficient privileges to copy files.